# Apache cordova - find someone with the same app installed and send informations is it possible?

Tags: cordova

I want to create a tinder like application with appache cordova. Just to improve myself.

I know how to use Cordova, geolocation, contacts, notifications ... But i can't see how to localize people with the same app in the same city or same street and exchange datas in the app with those two person. I just have this problem (ok it's a big part of the app :) but i want to improve myself and learn something new)

Could someone help me to find informations if it's possible or tell me i can't with apache cordova?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a broad subject so you won't get that exact answer either. You are gonna need a back-end server (written in any language you prefer) that will be aware of all the clients out there. When someone downloads the application, he/she creates an account so the user will be registered on that back-end server. Now as you at the same time collect information to do the [push notifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) and about the location (GPS) of user, for example.

Then, when your user wants to browser other users, the client app asks the back-end server for user listing. User can then usually perform some activities on that users such as send on [Instant Message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_messaging) or ask he/she as a friend or whatever you wish they to be able to do. In the end, it is all about the back-end server which has the information about all the users and how to connect to them (push notifications or just plain HTTP responses).

You got the idea?

Comment: Yeah i understand but i don't know tecnically how to say to the app  to send data anywhere anytime when the phone is using the app or when the phone is in the pocket of someone. For the rest of the app i can understand how to do :) thanks for your help

Comment: For example Tinder doesn't poll for the GPS location of it's client devices all the time. It only stores the last location of user (when he/she was looking for other users) and based on that, offers that user as a match for users who look for matches. So the GPS coordinates are only updated to server when you start to match for new users (to know which ones are close to you). It is like two-way thing, when you browse people through, it is done based on your location at that moment and when other people browse, your last location (stored when you were browsing) is used for distance.

Comment: Ok thanks i didn't expect that. I thought tinder was shaking data more times than just when people was searching people around themselves. But for me it's important to be able to know the position of people more often. Do you know if it's possible? and how with cordova. I don't ask code, i would like to know if it's possible and if it's ok, what plugins to use or whatever

Comment: That would use huge amounts of battery and network capacity and I don't think people like to tracked like that in real-time because privacy.

Comment: Yeah i agree but it's just to be able to really be in contact with people next to them in reality not 1 hour or 1 day before.

Comment: I really want to know if : 1 - is it possible? 2 - if yes, is it possible with apache cordova? 3 - if not, is it possible with natives languages?

Comment: Well, since everyone is playing around with Tinder all the time, it keeps updating fast enough, right? :) Seriously speaking, I assume that you can do the real-time tracking as background application with plugin such as [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) but beware of the angry users complaining about huge battery usage and privacy concerns. All you need to implement is application that runs also on background that like once a minute asks Android for GPS location and sends it via AJAX to server.

Comment: ok thanks guy i think it's a part of what i was searching. I can start with this. And , sorry last thing, how facebook can send notification when the app is not open? Because it's integrated to the OS? like mails? or it's another thing (native development only or cordova could be able to do it). I will not implement the not open app mecanism just what you explain me before but it's just a bonus to understand something more :)

Comment: If I understood you right, Facebook just uses the Push notifications to tell about new messages or from new friend invitations which are usable from Cordova too with the [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).

Comment: Happy to help. If you think this answer helped you to solve your problem though, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it for future reference to indicate it was correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the way to do that is make your app to submit the location every x minutes (or when the user likes someone, then submit its location -consider a kind of age mechanism so you dont have to send it everytime), then each user can search for people around using its own current-location to query with a radius of, ie: 100m. When you have the list of users you should have a mechanism to ask for authorization (private messaging, I think that notifications are too intrusive for that kind of app but...), if its accepted then you make both users "friends" and allow them to send private messages (or instant messages) and view each others profile... just a suggestion. Hope you find it useful.
Have a good day!

Comment: ok. My probleme is how to ask to the application to send geolocation information of one utilisator when the app is not open every X minutes. If the guy who use the app wants to send his geolocation, i know how to check data and save on a database, no prob. But i would like the app automaticaly send those data to the server. Do you undestand my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success using this geofencing plugin which means that you do not need to constantly poll - it is triggered when the phone moves a large distance: https://github.com/radshag/PhoneGap-Geofencing.

Two options- either you register large movements, or you keep setting a 200m fence around the person and update when they cross the boundary.

Ask if this doesn't make sense - I have made it work quite well.

Comment: Hi, i'm looking for information on this plugin and i will told you if it's what i was searching. Thanks :)